# How to properly extract an Array from a cURL JSON?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to extract a user profile picture from Instagram but I can't manage to successfully `echo` the needed Array.

```
$url="https://www.instagram.com/selenagomez/media/";

//  Initiate curl
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
// Execute
$json=curl_exec($ch);
// Closing
curl_close($ch);

$result = json_decode($json, true);

echo $result[0]["profile-picture"];
```

I'm getting: `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in test.php on line 23`

Also tried to exclude the 2nd JSON parameter (`true`) and it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON for above URL is as follows:

[image]

[Source](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)

So, you need to adjust your grip to this:

```
$results['items'][0]['user']['profile_picture'];
```

This will output

```
https://igcdn-photos-a-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfl1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12918537_1719366751611008_1708400518_a.jpg
```

Go back one level in the tree to get `user` property with all its children

```
$user = $results['items'][0]['user'];
```